# How to get List of items from existing List matching a keyword and ignoring case (case-insensitive)?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a `SeachBar` in Xamarin Forms, and `ListView` that shows suggestions from existing list of cities. I want to get list of items matching search keyword irrespective of it being uppercase or lowercase.

For that I am having a `List`. I want to Search items from that list and get `List` of items that matched the search keyword ignoring the case. I am having a code for getting list of items that matched keyword. I just want it to include items that match search keyword ignoring the case of letters.

(Please note that here I want to return a `List` of the matched items and not `bool` whether match exists. So please do not close this question or mark similar to the one that returns `bool`.)

Here is my code

```
List<string> allCities = new List<string> { "Mumbai", "Redmond", "Cambridge", "London", "Moscow", "New York", "Chicago"};

void SearchList()
{
    string keyword = "mum";
    var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.Contains(keyword));
    ListView.ItemSource = citiesSearched;
}
```

I have tried with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` but I was getting `Error No overload for Contains takes 2 arguments.`

This was the modification:

```
var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.Contains(keyword, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
// And
var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

in both the statements I got the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: @ThomasHeijtink, No, this question is different. Here I want to get List of items that matches a keyword. Question you suggested targets on `bool` whether keyword exists in the `List`. Both questions target different return types.

Comment: But the idea is exactly the same. But you have a list of strings. The answer I suggested addresses the situation of a single string. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no overload of `String.Contains` that accepts a `StringComparison` or a `StringComparer`, but you *can* use `IndexOf` with a `StringComparison`, and use the fact that `IndexOf` returns -1 if the substring isn't found, or the index of the substring within the larger string otherwise. So you can use:

```cs
var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(
    c => c.IndexOf(SearchBar.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
```

If you want it to be culture-sensitive for a specific `CultureInfo`, you can use `CultureInfo.CompareInfo` to get a `CompareInfo`, then `CompareInfo.IndexOf` with `CompareOptions.IgnoreCase` to perform a culture-sensitive case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert to lower case (or upper case) each element of the list before calling `Contains` **and** also the keyword. the idea is to have both terms in common case:

```
var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.toLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
```

Try it with:

```
string keyword = "mum";
List<string> allCities = new List<string> { "Mumbai", "numUmbus","Redmond", "Cambridge", "London", "Moscow", "New York", "Chicago"};
var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
foreach (var s in citiesSearched)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: There are some cultural quirks that make lower-casing (or upper-casing) a string before a case-sensitive "contains" work differently to just using a culture-sensitive, case-insensitive comparison. I *think* using IndexOf (as per my answer) is a more reliable approach, but I readily admit I don't have a specific example to hand.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're totally right, however, the OP didn't mention any of that. Besides, do you think from the post that he/she needs to go into such depths. He/she might have come out with more doubts after reading your approach.

Comment: Would you *expect* the OP to specifically say "I want it to work even in corner cases"? That would be a little odd. And yes, I think in general it's better to post code which works even in corner cases. I don't see why you'd think that my approach would cause more "doubts". It's just using `IndexOf` to find something instead of `Contains`... that's not particularly strange IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, your code worked in the first go. But however can you explain how? Other answers needed some modifications as I want to get result irrespective of `keyword = "mum"` OR `keyword = "Mum"`.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin: Well this answer expects the lower-case version of the city name to contain the keyword, which it won't do if the keyword is "Mum". My approach just uses a case-insensitive search instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was missing `keyword.ToLower()`, I forgot, thanks to @JunedKhanMomin for mentioning it, it works for "Mum". Sorry if it caused a missunderstanding.

Comment: @JonSkeet ">But however can you explain how?", this is what I was talking about...

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: I edited my answer slightly to make it clearer - but it's really not terribly complicated. Note the bit about how it actually worked though...

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> allCities = new List<string> { "Mumbai", "Redmond", "Cambridge", 
"London", "Moscow", "New York", "Chicago"};

void SearchList()
{
    string keyword = "mum";
    var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
    ListView.ItemSource = citiesSearched;
}
```

transform your text to lower case before the check should do the trick.

Comment: See my comments on the answer by Javier Silva Ortíz - I believe this may have problems. I suspect the OP *wants* the ItemSource to be the query rather than a single value - this is the source of items for a list, so it's natural for there to be more than one value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution based on one of the fastest string API with `StringComparison` enum flag:

```
List<string> allCities = new List<string> { "Mumbai", "Redmond", "Cambridge", "London", "Moscow", "New York", "Chicago"};

void SearchList()
{
    string keyword = "mum";
    var citiesSearched = allCities.Where(c => c.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    ListView.ItemSource = new List(citiesSearched);
}
```